# Exporting data into a table not working with Access Denied error

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I have a table in a database `myDatabase` in Amazon RDS. Let it be `myTable`.

```
use myDatabase;

SELECT * from myTable INTO OUTFILE 'myFile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES 
TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get this error

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user '<<UserName>>'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I tried running this command

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '<<UserName>>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<<password>>';
flush privileges; 


0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's 
properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use 
ALTER USER statement for this operation.
```

I get this warning.
And 
I am not able to export the table into a `.CSV` file at all.

Any idea on how to solve it ? Any thoughts on the steps which might have gone wrong ?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? Did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user has the `FILE` privilege.

> FILE
>
> Affects the following operations and server behaviors:
>
> Enables reading and writing files on the server host using the LOAD DATA and SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statements and the LOAD_FILE()
>   function. A user who has the FILE privilege can read any file on the
>   server host that is either world-readable or readable by the MySQL
>   server. (This implies the user can read any file in any database
>   directory, because the server can access any of those files.)
>
> Enables creating new files in any directory where the MySQL server has write access. This includes the server's data directory containing
>   the files that implement the privilege tables.

- [manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file)